# How do I use 'stop' (range) to create a missig multipliers worksheet?

Tags: python, for-loop, math, range, calculator

I'm trying to write a program that asks for a times table and then print the times table for numbers from 3 to 12, but with the multiplier missing. In its place there's meant to be an answer box made of square brackets around a space, like this: [ ]

Here's the code I have so far:

```
inp = int(input('Times table: '))
stepinp = int(input('Step: '))

start = inp * 3
step = inp * stepinp
stop = 

for n in range(start, stop, step):
  print(f'{inp} x [ ] = {n}')
```

Here's the output I get (when I do 'stop = inp * 12):

```
Times table: 2
Step: 1
2 x [ ] = 6
2 x [ ] = 8
2 x [ ] = 10
2 x [ ] = 12
2 x [ ] = 14
2 x [ ] = 16
2 x [ ] = 18
2 x [ ] = 20
2 x [ ] = 22
```

Here's the output I expect:

```
Times table: 2
Step: 1
2 x [ ] = 6
2 x [ ] = 8
2 x [ ] = 10
2 x [ ] = 12
2 x [ ] = 14
2 x [ ] = 16
2 x [ ] = 18
2 x [ ] = 20
2 x [ ] = 22
2 x [ ] = 24
```

But 'n' is not just meant to be inp * 12
The 'step' purpose is to increase the multiplier by 'step' each row.
For example, if the step number is 1 then the output is the code seen above. If the step number is 4 then the output:

```
Times table: 5
Step: 4
5 x [ ] = 15
5 x [ ] = 35
5 x [ ] = 55
```

The multipliers are 3, 7, 11 (5 * 3 = 15, 5 * 7 = 35, etc)

So, how do I create this relationship between 'step' and 'stop'?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `step`:

```
inp = int(input('Times table: '))
stepinp = int(input('Step: '))

start = inp * 3
step = inp * stepinp
stop = 

for n in range(start, stop + step, step):
  print(f'{inp} x [ ] = {n}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was stop = inp * 13, not inp * 12...